# Equivalent of Firefox Plugin "Aero Window Title" in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, plugins, user-interface, aero

**Windows 7 / Aero UI / Chrome Frame Issue.**

In Mozilla Firefox I use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/aero-window-title/) plugin purely to stop my white-space above my tabs disappearing so that I can easily grab my window and move it around as I please...

Does anyone know of an equivalent in Chrome?
 It bugs me that there is no space to move the window as I please...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, this isn't something that can be changed by plugins (to the best of my knowledge). It has been raised as a feature request at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67491 which you may wish to star and watch for updates. It has also been the subject of debates e.g. [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=25edfff443ecb449&hl=en) and [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=209d61ef9e5a27cf&hl=en) but without any solutions proposed.

However, you **can** grab and move the window by using the tiny space between the "new tab" button and the Windows minimize button. It's not perfect, but it works, and you quickly get quite fast at hitting the right area (can you hear the voice of experience?).